# Mysql - key with null value

Tags: mysql, null

I have 2 tables:

```
news_item:
id | catagory_id
1 | 2
2 | 100
3 | 50
4 | 3


news_item_lang:
id | id_origin | lang | title
1 | 1 | en | This is title in english
2 | 1 | ru | This is title in russian
3 | 1 | fr | This is title in french
4 | 2 | NULL | This is multilanguage !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! title
5 | 2 | en | ......       ---------------------- This is WRONG case, because we have row with id = 4 already, which says no needs in row with lang = 'en'.
```

So, how can I be sure that I have only one row with lang = NULL or many rows for each language? Pair "id_origin - lang" is an unique key. 
id_origin is an external key for table news_item.

UPD:

I want to get translation for news with id = 1.

Translation can exists, so for each languages (en, fr, ru...) I can get translation use Left Join news_item and news_item_lang. But in some cases (id = 2) no needs translation, so for each languages I get the same row with field `lang` = NULL. So, translation for html page

```
/en/news/2.html
/ru/news/2.html
/fr/news/2.html
```

will be the same with title "This is multilanguage !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! title".

Comment: Are you looking for a mysql query to find out the number of rows which contain "NULL" or you want to make sure that you have only one `NULL` value in your entire db? For the second case, before inserting the values into DB you could check your db using your application language and then insert it. If this solution doesn't work could you please explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make sure that I have only one NULL value in field 'lang' with id = 2 OR!!! I have not filed 'lang' with value NULL, but then I can have field 'lang' with values en, ru, fr... One moment, I make some update.

Comment: Are you trying to stop data being entered (like id #5)? Or do you want a SQL script that shows when an article (like article #2) has both a multilanguage and a single language?

Comment: >Are you trying to stop data being entered (like id #5)? - Yes, I am! I want to prevent an article (like article #2) has both a multilanguage and a single language.

Comment: Smells to poor database design.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` means indeterminate, which means you don't know what it is. In this case, instead of `NULL`, use something like "mult", for multiple languages since you DO know that it's multi-language. `NULL` introduces a lot of hassle and if you don't need it, don't use it.

Then you can set the `lang` column to be unique, and not accept nulls, and you're done!

Comment: Bu I still can have filed "lang" with values "en, ru, fr, ..." and also "mult". Value "mult" do not exclude values "en, ru, fr, ...". If I have set of "en, ru, fr, ..." and "mult" - can I somehow select only row with "mult"?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Can you explain more?

Comment: I prevent to duplicate rows (id_origin - lang) "1-en", "1-ru", "1-fr" by adding unique key on fields `id_origin` and `lang`. But when I have rows "2-en", "2-NULL" - this is duplicate. I select row by using "ON id_origin = 2 AND (lang = 'here is current lang, for example en' OR lang IS NULL)". I thought I can add new key or something like that to table without checking on duplicate from php.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

If you have a database just like in your question then try the following code:

```
SELECT 
news_item_lang.id,
id_origin,lang,
title 
FROM news_item_lang
LEFT JOIN news_item ON  news_item.id = news_item_lang.id_origin
WHERE id_origin NOT IN (SELECT id_origin FROM  news_item_lang  WHERE lang is null)

UNION ALL 

SELECT news_item_lang.id,id_origin,lang,title FROM news_item_lang
LEFT JOIN news_item ON  news_item.id = news_item_lang.id_origin
WHERE lang is null

ORDER BY id
```

**Solution 2**

If you just want to prevent data like that then the solution is you have to check your database before inserting using your application language (like PHP) and you can use the following query :

```
 SELECT id_origin FROM  news_item_lang  WHERE lang is null
```

After executing the query if any row is found then don't enter the data (otherwise enter)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want this stopped, you need to implement a trigger along the lines of (consider this pseudocode)

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_foobar 
BEFORE INSERT ON news_item_lang
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF  (new.lang IS NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM news_item_lang WHERE new.id_origin = news_item_lang.id_origin)) THEN
  SIGNAL 'Single Language already Exists'
END IF

IF (new.lang IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM news_item_lang WHERE new.id_origin = news_item_lang.id_origin AND news_item_lang.lang IS NULL)) THEN 
  SIGNAL 'Multi Language already Exists'
END IF

END
```